# Slow playing of Mp3 in Windows Mobile 6 SndPlaySync

Tags: windows-mobile, mp3, windows-mobile-6

I'm trying to play mp3 files from my winows mobile application using the newly supported mp3-playing function SndPlaySync ( also tried SndPlayAsync ).
I made the simplest program, just attached the function to a WM_KEYDOWN event. ( code attached below ). But stil there is always 0.5-2 seconds of wait before
the program plays the mp3. When i simply use PlaySound, and try to play a .wav file, it works instateneously. What can i do?

Code :

This works too slow

```
case WM_KEYDOWN: 
    PlaySound(c_szMid,NULL,NULL);
    HSOUND hSound;
    HRESULT hr;
    SndOpen(c_szMid, &hSound);
    hr = SndPlayAsync(hSound, 0);
    hr = SndClose(hSound);
```

And this works fast :

```
case WM_KEYDOWN: 
    PlaySound(c_szMid,NULL,NULL);
```

Would be grateful for any ideas!

Thanks!

Dan

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that an `mp3` file is compressed, whereas a `wav` isn't.

So the delay might be the time it takes to read the `mp3` file into memory and decompress it, which doesn't have to happen with the `wav` file.

I'm not sure how you'd verify this though.

Answer (score 0):

Is that code right?  Right now you call PlaySound (which is synchronous) followed by the async version.  To me that should be playing the sound twice.

Also, if you try using [PlaySound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa909766.aspx) with the SND_ASYNC flag what behavior do you see?

Answer (score 0):

I actually added the code where i tried SndPlayAsync, but it worked the same with SndPlaySync.

I actually narrowed down the problem - Even When i try to play wav files using 
PlaySound(with Sync flag) and using SndPlaySync, SndPlaySync runs twice as slow :(

I'll open a new question about it.